# What is the right way to use hyperref options with Tufte handout class?

Tags: hyperref, incompatibility, tufte, document-configuration

**EDIT**: I must clarify that the example below *works* with tufte-latex-3.5.0, but doesn't work in older versions. The accepted solution is a good workaround for older versions (<3.0.0) were `nohyper` option doesn't work.

---

(**EDIT**: Older version of) `tufte-handout` class doesn't seem to play well with hyperref, probably because `tufte-handout` loads `hyperref` with its own set of options. How can I set up the document so that hyperref can be loaded normally?

I thought that the option `nohyper` would solve the problem but it doesn't.

*The idea is to be able to have a simple document that compiles correctly whether I change `tufte-handout` by `article` in the `\documentclass` command.*

Here is an example code (not working)

```
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-handout} 
% but works with \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false, pdftex, pdfauthor={}, pdftitle={ hyperref.pdf}, pdfsubject={subject}, pdfkeywords={}]{hyperref} 
% but works with \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Body text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: What `hyperref` options do you want to set/change with the `tufte-handout` class?  Can you use the `\hypersetup` command?

Comment: Any option in `hyperref` seems to break the compatibility (for example, the ones in the example in my question). `hypersetup` (+1) is an option but I just wanted to change the documentclass line, for things that already compiled for `article`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\@ifpackageloaded` command to run other commands depending on whether or not the `hyperref` package has already been loaded.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}% or article

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  % do this if hyperref is already loaded
  % (e.g., if you're using the tufte-handout
  % document class)
  \hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={},
    pdftitle={Tufte-LaTeX document},
    pdfsubject={subject},
    pdfkeywords={}
  }%
}{%
  % do this if the hyperref package hasn't
  % been loaded yet
  \usepackage[
    hyperfootnotes=false,
    pdftex,
    pdfauthor={},
    pdftitle={article},
    pdfsubject={subject},
    pdfkeywords={}]{hyperref}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Body text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I also figured out that `nohyper` option doesn't work for old versions of `tufte-latex`. For that your solution is a good workaround.

Comment: @alfC: The `nohyper` option was added to the code May 19, 2009. So it looks like it should exist in all versions _after_ (but not including) 3.0.0.