# Verse and Tufte-Handout Incompatibility

Tags: hyperref, tufte, verse

I am attempting to use the `tufte-handout` document class with the `verse` package. However, it seems that `tufte-handout` loads `hyperref` by default and this causes the following error in `verse.sty`:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \theHpoemline already defined.
```

Researching options for resolution led me to this answer:
[What is the right way to use hyperref options with Tufte handout class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66526/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-hyperref-options-with-tufte-handout-class)

Loading with the `nohyper` option on the `tufte-handout` document class does allow the `verse` package to function, but I also need the `hyperref` package. (Loading `hyperref` after the fact still results in the same error.)

How do I manage this apparent incompatibility?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
    A sprig, with its flower, I break.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a very bad mistake for *any* class to load `hyperref` unconditionally, because the user might want to load other packages and this will, in many cases, create incompatibilities, as `hyperref` needs to be called last (with a few exceptions).

Comment: @egreg: I agree with that, but isn't it equally bad from `verse` package designers to define a `\theHpoemline` command while it's known that `\theH....` commands are introduced by `hyperref` automatically?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work: Temporarily disable the loading of `hyperref` and load it after `verse`. `verse` (unnecessarily?) defines `\theHpoemline` counter format, in my point of view.

```
\documentclass[nohyper]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
    A sprig, with its flower, I break.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

A dirty workaround, without direct changes in `verse.sty`

Since `verse.sty` defines a counter `poemline`, `hyperref` will do automatically a `\theHpoemline` definition. However, this is bad, since

`\newcommand*{\theHpoemline}{\arabic{verse@envctr}.\arabic{poemline}}`

is used in `verse.sty`.

A workaround is to use `\providecommand` temporarily instead of `\newcommand`, which does not complain about already existing commands and after `verse` is loaded, switch back to `\newcommand`.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
%\hypersetup{colorlinks=true} Not needed, just for debug
\let\orignewcommand\newcommand  % store the original \newcommand
\let\newcommand\providecommand  % make \newcommand behave like \providecommand
\RequirePackage{verse}
\let\newcommand\orignewcommand  % use the original `\newcommand` in future
\makeatletter
% Use the original definition from verse.sty
\renewcommand*{\theHpoemline}{\arabic{verse@envctr}.\arabic{poemline}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{first}

\chapter{second}
\begin{verse}
    A sprig, with its flower, I break.
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works on the MWE, but beyond this complexity, does not work. (The sample-handout.tex file included with tufte still breaks with deferred loading on hyperref when verse is also loaded.)  I'll see if I can complicate my MWE to replicate.

Comment: @twip: Yes, I feared that it wouldn't work for a larger document

Comment: Compiles with the updated workaround. Thank you for digging deeper.

Comment: @twip: You're welcome. Happy TeXing ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved it tidily by loading package `\hyperref` before loading `\verse`.